# Moving to home from pet store

Tags: harbour

I played my pawn to pet store.

The card text is:

While there is a person here, nobody can visit their home building.

But if I want, in my next turn, go to my home building, can I do that?

Once I lift my pawn, nobody is at the pet store, so the text is no longer valid.